# Running Gramex on new Ubuntu 16.04 Installation

Tags: gramex

I'm having trouble running gramex in Ubuntu 16.04.

Running it inside docker works fine, which leads me to suspect that I'm missing some dependency, but can't seem to figure out which one.

This is the error that I get, any ideas?

```
INFO    22-Mar 11:33:21 install Gramex 1.31.0 | guide --browser=/welcome | /gramex/apps/guide | Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 13 2018, 01:15:57)  [GCC 7.2.0]
WARNING 22-Mar 11:33:21 config Missing config: /.config/gramexdata/mail/gramexmail.yaml
WARNING 22-Mar 11:33:21 watcher watch directory /.config/gramexdata/mail does not exist
INFO    22-Mar 11:33:21 config No config found: /.config/gramexdata/mail/gramexmail.yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/anaconda3/envs/gramex/bin/gramex", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(commandline())
    File "/anaconda3/envs/gramex/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gramex/__init__.py", line 172, in commandline
callback(**kwargs)
    File "anaconda3/envs/gramex/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gramex/install.py", line 539, in run
gramex.init(cmd=AttrDict(app=app_config['run']))
    File "anaconda3/envs/gramex/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gramex/__init__.py", line 279, in init
callback = getattr(services, key)(conf[key])
    File "anaconda3/envs/gramex/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gramex/services/__init__.py", line 133, in app
if ioloop._running:
AttributeError: 'AsyncIOMainLoop' object has no attribute '_running'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gramex 1.31 is not compatible with Tornado 5.0. This will be resolved in Gramex 1.32, which is due on 31 Mar 2018, and is [tracked here](https://code.gramener.com/cto/gramex/issues/370)